# Clipping soil survey map service to feature class?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-online, map-service, feature-service

I'm guessing this is not possible but is there any way to clip a Esri map service such as the Soil Survey Map for a another feature polygon? http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/Soil_Survey_Map/MapServer

I know it's a not a feature service but what is confusing is how if you zoom in far enough it will show the soil series information.  What I would like to do is clip it to a smaller area like less than 1000 acres based on a polygon feature class.  Maybe someone knows of another feature service available that would show the soil survey down to the soil series detail like this Esri map service does?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be wanting to perform a graphic clip of a data frame containing the map service you mention, by using a selected polygon from a feature class.

To do this take a look at the Clip Options on the Data Frame tab of your Data Frame's Properties.

There is online help on [Clipping the Data Frame available here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s90000000q000000.htm).

Comment: thanks for the answer.  That is not quite what I'm looking for.  The Soil Survey map service displays labels but if I clip to a shape with the frame it will both cutoff labels and exclude labels of some of the soil types.  I would also like to change the symbology of the different soil type features.  I really need a feature service here.  Was hoping there was one out there but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: No problem - I was not sure exactly what you were wanting but the inclusion of 'arcmap' amongst your four tags made me think it was this